# Improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{x^{m+n+1}} \ dx=\frac{n! {(m-1)}!}{(m+n)!}.$

Tags: calculus, integration, induction, improper-integrals, special-functions

How can I prove that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{x^{m+n+1}} \ dx=\frac{n! {(m-1)}!}{(m+n)!}\quad ?$$

I tried to do induction on $n$ and on $m$, separately, but I could only do the base case ($n=1$ and $m=1$). I don't know how to use the induction hypothesis in the inductive step.

Comment: That is just $\int_0^\infty x^{- m - 1} dx = \dfrac{1}{m + 1}$...

Comment: That looks wrong since your integral is $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{m+1}}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-m-1}dx$, which A) is easy and B) doesn't depend on $n$ so the answer cannot depend on $n$ either....

Comment: You have this confused with the Beta function, $B(x, y) = \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt$, I think.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty x^{-m-1}\,dx$ does not converge for any real number $m$, because one endpoint or the other will cause divergence.

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be written:
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x^n}{x^{m+n+1}}dx=\int^{\infty}_{0} x^nx^{-m-n-1} dx \\
=\int^{\infty}_{0} x^{-m-1} dx=\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{1}{x^{m+1}} dx
$$
which does not converge (hence we cannot evaluate the integral). 
You may be confusing the integral you have with the Beta function, which has the representation
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{n+m}}dx=\frac{(n-1)!(m-1)!}{(n+m-1)!}.
$$